# AWS Aurora RDS Instance Failed to create

Tags: aws-sdk

I am having the following error:

`cloudformation rds::db::instance creation failed.... error message is "Invalid master password"`

Anyone having a fix for this issue? Image:

[image]

Comment: Enhanced formatting + streamlined image

Comment: I found a good example. https://gist.github.com/sjparkinson/e1c2f74475d2e8625ce4af85b892ab13

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue/error with cloudformation. For me it was because I was creating an Aurora(MySql) cluster with two instances in the cluster and I was passing the wrong parameters to the Instances. Because I had the wrong properties, AWS was viewing the Instances as stand alone and was giving me this error. Check each property on which you need for clusters or instances:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html

Comment: I also have the same issue, But I don't know about the parameters, 

```RDSdatabase1 = t.add_resource(
    rds.DBInstance(
        "RDSDatabase1",
        Engine="aurora-mysql",
        EngineVersion="5.7.12",
        DBInstanceClass=Ref(dbclass),
        DBClusterIdentifier=Ref(DBCluster),
        DependsOn=DBSubnetGroup,
        DBSubnetGroupName=Ref(DBSubnetGroup),
        DBSecurityGroups=[Ref(DBSecurityGroup)],
        DBParameterGroupName=Ref(DBParameterGroup),
        MultiAZ=True,
    ))```
This is my DBinstance and 2nd one is also somewhat same but the name is different

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was because of the characters in `username` and `password`.
AWS doesn't allow you to use `-` in database username and also it doesn't allow you to use `@/` etc in the password.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this configuration under your `cloudformation template`, 
Even if you specify DBcluster you need to add `username` and `password` in you individual `DBInstance` as well.

```
MasterUsername="Username",
MasterUserPass="Password",
```